# How Can I set Dynamic Snackbar Colors in Compose in a Scaffold

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

My app has a lot of colour coding in it, and I can't figure out how to cleanly change the colour of a Snackbar action in a scaffold based on the action that shows the snackbar.

I have a composable, and inside there is a lazy list with an item that can be clicked.  When you click it, that row has a specific colour associated with it.

Now, the click listener isn't a composable itself, I can't create a snackbar in it.  I have to use the scaffolds snackbarHost

```
onClick {
   scope.launch {
            val snackbarResult = scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                message = "message",
                actionLabel = "action"
            )
            when (snackbarResult) {
                SnackbarResult.ActionPerformed -> do something
                SnackbarResult.Dismissed -> do something
            }
        }
]
```

From here, I can't choose or set a colour.

In the scaffold, where I can make the snackbar, I can't get a colour back to it as it only has the snackbarData

```
Scaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        snackbarHost = {
            SnackbarHost(it) { snackbarData ->
                Snackbar(          
                    actionColor = I want a color here!
                    snackbarData = snackbarData
                )
            }
        },
```

Using this set up, if 2 snackbars are triggered back to back, I can action both.  You action the second, and then you can action the first.  **I like this functionality.**

The only way I can get a colour in this way, is to set a global variable in the onClick but that is incredibly gross.  Changing a local variable in the same file does not work.

Alternatively, I can trigger a recomposition via the ViewModel which will trigger showing a snackbar with the correct colour, but then I lose the functionality of triggering 2 items and still being capable of actioning both snackbars one after the other.

I even tried putting the colour into the action label so i could split it out, but I can't instantiate the existing SnackbarDataImpl to then recreate it without it because it's private.  I would have to copy the entire scaffold implementation to simply add a colour this way as the host has to come from the scaffold

Is there some better way I can do this? It's way too complicated for something as simple as wanting to set a colour based on the action?

Comment: For the moment I'm going with a global ThreadLocal<Color> but i feel dirty

Answer (score 4):

There is a working solution using **Material 3 API**:
It works by extending `SnackbarVisuals` instance to add custom properties.

[image]

In `build.gradle`:

```
implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.0.1"
```

Sample App:

```
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.ExperimentalMaterial3Api
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material3.Snackbar
import androidx.compose.material3.SnackbarData
import androidx.compose.material3.SnackbarDuration
import androidx.compose.material3.SnackbarHost
import androidx.compose.material3.SnackbarHostState
import androidx.compose.material3.SnackbarVisuals
import androidx.compose.material3.Text

data class CustomSnackbarVisuals(
    override val message: String,
    override val duration: SnackbarDuration = SnackbarDuration.Short,
    val containerColor: Color = Color.White,
    val contentColor: Color = Color.Red,
    override val actionLabel: String? = null,
    override val withDismissAction: Boolean = falser
) : SnackbarVisuals

@Composable
fun AppContent() {
    val snackbarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
    val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    Scaffold(
        snackbarHost = {
            SnackbarHost(hostState = snackbarHostState, snackbar = { snackbarData: SnackbarData ->
                val customVisuals = snackbarData.visuals as? CustomSnackbarVisuals
                if (customVisuals != null) {
                    Snackbar(
                        snackbarData = snackbarData,
                        contentColor = customVisuals.contentColor,
                        containerColor = customVisuals.containerColor
                    )
                } else {
                    Snackbar(snackbarData = snackbarData)
                }
            })
        }
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.padding(it).fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
        ) {
            Button(onClick = {
                scope.launch {
                    snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                        CustomSnackbarVisuals(
                            message = "Hello from Red",
                            contentColor = Color.Red
                        )
                    )
                }
            }) {
                Text("Red")
            }
            Button(onClick = {
                scope.launch {
                    snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
                        CustomSnackbarVisuals(
                            message = "Hello from Blue",
                            contentColor = Color.Blue
                        )
                    )
                }
            }) {
                Text("Blue")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, I'll give that a try this weekend, thanks!

Comment: Is extending SnackbarData semantically better than SnackbarVisuals?

Comment: The problem is you are not instanciating SnackbarData

Comment: What about the action button's text color? Didn't find any way to change it in your code.

Comment: It works! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your best bet is to have your `ViewModel` store the snackbar color:

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var snackBarColor by mutableStateOf(Color.Blue)
    (...)
}
```

And in the `Scaffold`:

```
Scaffold(
    scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
    snackbarHost = {
        SnackbarHost(it) { snackbarData ->
            Snackbar(          
                actionColor = myViewModel.snackBarColor,
                snackbarData = snackbarData
            )
    }
},
```

So now when calling the `Snackbar`, also set the `snackBarColor` in the `ViewModel`:

```
onClick {
   myViewModel.snackBarColor = Color.Red
   scope.launch {
        val snackbarResult = scaffoldState.snackbarHostState.showSnackbar(
            message = "message",
            actionLabel = "action"
        )
        when (snackbarResult) {
            SnackbarResult.ActionPerformed -> do something
            SnackbarResult.Dismissed -> do something
        }
    }
}
```

As long you have the same instance of the `MyViewModel` both in the `Scaffold` and where you are calling the `onClick`, the `Scaffold` will observe the `snackBarColor` from `MyViewModel` and update automatically when it changes.

Comment: This actually doesn't work.  When the colour gets changed in the VM on the 2nd press, it changes the colour of the currently visible snackbar.  Even when i do a .copy() on the color value before setting it. It's really weird, but it has to be a global variable for this to work.   Also, I don't like to go  val someValue = viewModel.value, I try to keep any communication into the fragment/composable solely through observing changes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use something like this:

```
var color by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(Color.Red) }

Snackbar(
    actionColor = color,
    ...
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately doing anything through recomposition removes the ability to have multiple snackbars if the user actions 2 items back to back.